# AngularJS , passing object by reference in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to build a customize checkbox by write a directive.

```
App.directive('preferredCheckBox', function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
require: '?ngModel',
scope: {
    ngModel: '='
},
link: function(scope, elem,attrs){
    elem.bind('click', function() {
        scope.ngModel = !scope.ngModel;

        //alert("clicked");
    })
},

template: "<div ng-if='ngModel'> <span class='ion-ios-star text-red' style='font-size:2em'></span></div> " +
          "<div ng-if='!ngModel'> <span class='ion-ios-star-outline text-red' style='font-size:2em'></span></div>"
 }

});
```

This is how I call the directive

```
<preferred-check-box ng-model="item.isChecked"></preferred-check-box>
```

The directive work fine for display purpose.
But if I click on the checkbox, it doesn't change the value of "item.isChecked"

In my opinion, inside the directive :

```
 scope: {
        ngModel: '='
 },
link: function(scope, elem,attrs){
    elem.bind('click', function() {
        scope.ngModel = !scope.ngModel;

        //alert("clicked");
    })
},
```

It just clone another "item.isChecked" value into its own local scope, during trigger the click function, it doesn't change the original "item.isChecked".

How can I handle this ? I want to pass ng-model by reference.

Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/tanch/rd0b1n4b/7/
When I click the text "checked", it should change to "unchecked", vice versa.

Comment: your `preferred-check-box` is inside of ng-repeat ?

Comment: yes. it is inside the ng-repeat

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tanch/rd0b1n4b/7/

Comment: when click on the text, it should change "checked" to "unchecked", vice versa

Comment: only proper way to implements custom inputs is to override the $render method of the ngModel controller

Comment: @AnsonTan see my answer dont use $spply http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/rd0b1n4b/11/

```
link: function(scope, elem,attrs,ngModel){
        elem.bind('click', function() {
              ngModel.$setViewValue(!scope.ngModel);
              ngModel.$render();
            alert("clicked");
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `scope.$apply();` in your link function, just before the alert, to start the digest loop.